# How to infer difference of population proportion between two groups when proportion is small?

Tags: inference, proportion

I have a dataset where the issue is of this form.

There are two groups, Group A (N=5000) and Group B (N=1000). Let's say 5 people in Group A develop a certain disease, and only 2 in group B do.

Then the proportion for A is `5/5000` -> `0.001` and for B it is `2/1000` -> `0.002`.

How can I test if the proportion between these two groups is statistically significant?

The tests I found online rely on the Central Limit Theorem, such that `np>=10` and `n(1-p) >= 10`, which does not hold for my dataset. Are there any other approaches?

Comment: Use Fisher Exact Test per discussion in Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional approach would be to do a 2-sample test for a difference in proportions: In Minitab, results of this test are as shown below. The warning about the first P-value from a normal approximation causes doubt,
roughly for the reasons you mention.

However, the result from Fisher's exact test uses an exact hypergeometric
probability. It also shows no significant difference.

```
Test and CI for Two Proportions 

Sample  X     N  Sample p
1       5  5000  0.001000
2       2  1000  0.002000

Difference = p (1) - p (2)
Estimate for difference:  -0.001
95% upper bound for difference:  0.00143738
Test for difference = 0 (vs < 0):  
  Z = -0.67  P-Value = 0.250

* NOTE * The normal approximation may be 
inaccurate for small samples.

Fisher’s exact test: P-Value = 0.330
```

A direct hypergeometric computation in R can be argued
as follows. Suppose an urn contains $5000$ tokens marked A and $1000$ marked B. Seven tokens are taken
at random without replacement, corresponding to disease.
What is the probability five or fewer of those are marked A?

The answer is

$$\sum_{k=0}^5\frac{{5000 \choose k}{1000 \choose 7-k}}{{6000 \choose 7}} = 0.3302,$$

which agrees with the P-value from Fisher's exact test.

In R, the computation can be done in terms of a hypergeometric CDF:

```
phyper(5, 5000, 1000, 7)
[1] 0.330204
```

Here is a plot of this hypergeometric distribution. The P-value is the sum of the heights of the bars to the left of the vertical dotted line.

[image]