# Are the classic assumptions for Chi 2 test still valid?

Tags: statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test

For a 2*2 table, I want to use Chi 2 test
Are the classic assumptions (1# more than 80% of the contingency cells having expected values ­> 5, 2# no zero in the cells ) are still valid?
Is existence of number 1 assumption enough for considering the sample size as large?
For example if sample size=200 (sum of 4 cells = 200) is it acceptable to use chi 2 test relative to fisher exact test?

Comment: How about Fisher exact test? // Is there some reason not to show data?

Comment: @BruceET; I want to use chi 2 test for multiple 2*2 tables (reason not to show data)

Comment: I want to know is there any cut point for sample size (sum of 4 cells) to use either of chi 2 test or fisher exact test?

Comment: Suggest you look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/404331/how-to-infer-difference-of-population-proportion-between-two-groups-when-proport/404339#404339).